# How to make a an uppercase delta letter which is half coloured in black vertically?

Tags: symbols

The question is as simple as that. This is the kind of thing I want to achieve:

[image]

The idea is to make a symbol used for divided differences. It needs to be a true delta letter rather than a triangle, but actually it is not that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice solution finally:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox{\deltabox}

\newcommand{\divdiff}{
    \mathord{
    \mathpalette\makedivdiff\relax
    }
}

\newcommand{\makedivdiff}[2]{
    \sbox{\deltabox}{$#1\Delta$}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base), inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (char) {\usebox{\deltabox}};
        \fill[black] ([xshift=0.0\wd\deltabox,yshift=0.05\wd\deltabox]char.south) -- ([yshift=-0.05\wd\deltabox]char.north) -- ([xshift=-0.14\wd\deltabox,yshift=0.04\wd\deltabox]char.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

You can just call the symbol `\divdiff` when you need it, that gives this result:

[image]

I have to add that depending on the font that you are using, you may need to change very slightly the shifts that are used on the anchors of the triangle in the `\makedivdiff` command definition.

Answer (score 2):

The ◮ symbol is U+25EE in Unicode.  You can enable it with code like:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Or amsmath and fontspec.

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{New Computer Modern Math Regular}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\divdiff{\ifmmode%
    \textup{\symbolfont\symbol{"25EE}}%
\else%
    {\symbolfont\symbol{"25EE}}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
In text mode, {\divdiff}.

In math mode, \(\divdiff\increment\).
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Math sample]

Answer (score 1):

With `pict2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\divdiff}{\Delta{\mathpalette\divdiff@\relax}}
\newcommand{\divdiff@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Delta$}%
  \llap{% the black triangle
  \begin{picture}(0.54\wd\z@,\ht\z@)
  \moveto(0,0)
  \lineto(0.45\wd\z@,0)
  \lineto(0,0.95\ht\z@)
  \closepath
  \fillpath
  \end{picture}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\divdiff\scriptstyle\divdiff\scriptscriptstyle\divdiff$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see the trick if you paint the inner triangle in red.

[image]